# CasperJS never submits my form

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs

I've a simple form that I would like to fill out and submit in order to test that it works as expected.

Here is the code that is supposed to work, but actually does not.
I've already tried to submit the form in many ways, but neither of them triggered the page reload.

```
casper.test.begin('Showcase signup works', 2, function suite(test){
    casper.start('https://my.vidzor.com/accounts/signup/', function(){
        test.assertExists('form', 'Signup form found');
        this.fillSelectors('form', {
            'input[name="name"]': 'Test User',
            'input[name="email"]': 'test@example.com',
            'input[name="password"]': 'example',
            'input[name="password_confirm"]': 'example'
            }, true);
        this.click('button[type="submit"]');
        this.evaluate(function submitForm(){
            $('form').submit();
        });
        this.wait(10000);
        this.captureSelector('signup-form.png','input#id_name');
        var form_values = this.getFormValues('form');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(form_values));
        test.assertEqual(form_values.stage, "2");
    });
    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

There are many weird things going on that I've noticed.

1. `form_values` does not contain the name and email fields, even though they got filled
2. `captureSelector` takes a screenshot of the whole page; actually when I called it for 'form' only, then it captured different parts of the page
3. seemingly the page is never submitted (the 10 sec waiting time should be definitely more than necessary for the next page to load, and no errors are shown in the screenshot)

What do I miss here?

Comment: Everything that comes after `this.wait` must be inside of a step function. Put it inside of the `then` callback to `this.wait` and try again. And now for something completely different: please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: thanks, the problem was that I did not have these calls inside the wait callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep the asynchronous nature of CasperJS in mind. All `wait*` and `then*` functions are asynchronous step functions, which are used to schedule some behavior. If you call synchronous functions like `captureSelector` after the invocation of a `wait`, then there was no wait inbetween. They have to be scheduled inside of the `then` callback of `wait`:

```
this.wait(10000, function then(){
    this.captureSelector('signup-form.png','input#id_name');
    var form_values = this.getFormValues('form');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(form_values));
    test.assertEqual(form_values.stage, "2");
});
```

If the form submit handler is not asynchronous then the following should work without explicit wait:

```
casper.start('https://my.vidzor.com/accounts/signup/', function(){
    this.fillSelectors('form', {
        'input[name="name"]': 'Test User',
        'input[name="email"]': 'test@example.com',
        'input[name="password"]': 'example',
        'input[name="password_confirm"]': 'example'
    }, true);
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.captureSelector('signup-form.png','input#id_name');
    var form_values = this.getFormValues('form');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(form_values));
    test.assertEqual(form_values.stage, "2");
});
```